# Show that $e^{x}\geq (x+1)^{x+2}(1-x)$ holds for every $x\in[-1,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Show that $e^{x}\geq (x+1)^{x+2}(1-x)$ holds for every $x\in[-1,1]$

---

My approach is to consider first $x\in[0,1]$ .

Using $e^{x}\geq x+1$, it is sufficient to prove

$$x+1\geq (x+1)^{x+2}(1-x)$$

or

$$(x+1)^{x+1}(1-x)\leq 1$$

Here I get $(x+1)^{x+1}\geq 1$ and $1-x\leq 1$. So, this doesn't prove anything . For $x\in[-1,0]$ I got $(x+1)^{x+1}(1-x)\geq 1$ which is not true . How can I obtain solution using the inequality $e^{x}\geq x+1$ or any pre-calculus approaches ?

Comment: How is anything involving $e^x$ `algebra-precalculus`?

Comment: I may have made a mistake.  Assuming not: Let $~\displaystyle f(x) = (x+1)^{x+1}(1-x) - 1 \implies f(0) = 0~$ and $~f'(x) = \color{red}{\text{what ?}}~$ Further, let $~g(x) = -x + \text{ln}(x+1)(1-x) \implies g(0) = 0~$ and $~g'(x) = \color{red}{\text{what ?}}$

Comment: @user10354138 I mean avoiding derivative.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid derivatives?  For example, with respect to the answer of @user10354138, it seems to me that consideration of a Taylor series is a more advanced topic than basic examination of the derivative.

Comment: @user2661923 I respect too.  I just wanted to make an application of the well known inequalities, i.e.  C-S, Am-Gm, $e^{x}\geq x+1$ and etc.

Comment: My approach dovetails with the assumption that $~e^x \geq x+1.~$ That is, based on the assumption that $~e^x \geq x+1,~$ your own analysis reduced the problem to proving that $~f(x) \leq 0 ~: ~0 \leq x \leq 1.$

Comment: @user2661923 Do you mention $(x+1)^{x+1}(1-x)\leq 1$ ?

Comment: Re-examine $~f(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using $e^t\geqslant 1+t$ (*though its arguable whether definition of $e$ or the proof of this inequality is actually precalc*).   First note that we can equivalently show:
$$e^{\frac{x}{2+x}}\geqslant (1+x)\left(1-x \right)^{\frac1{2+x}}$$

Now using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),
$$(1-x)^{\frac1{2+x}}\leqslant 1-\frac{x}{2+x}=\frac2{2+x}$$
$$\implies (1+x)(1-x)^{\frac1{2+x}}\leqslant (1+x)\frac2{2+x}=1+\frac{x}{2+x}\leqslant e^{\frac{x}{2+x}}$$

Equality is possible when $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the $x$ in the index is to take log.  I don't think there is any way around that.

So let $x\in(-1,1)$ so we can take log.  We want to prove $x\geq (x+2)\log(1+x)+\log(1-x)$.  We use $\log(1+x)\leq x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13x^3$ (*) and so
\begin{align*}
RHS
&\leq (2+x)(x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13x^3)+(-x-\frac12 x^2-\frac13x^3)\\
&=x-\frac12x^2-\frac16x^3+\frac13x^4\\
&=x-\frac16x^2(3+x-2x^2)\\
&=x-\frac16x^2(x+1)(3-2x)\\
&\leq x=LHS
\end{align*}
where the last inequality works for $x\in(-1,\frac32]$.

Finally, since $e^x>0$ for all $x$ there is nothing to prove for $x=\pm 1$.

*Remark* (*): The bound $\log(1+x)\leq x$ is too weak and only gives $RHS\leq x+x^2$, hence we Taylor expand to $x^3$ with Lagrange remainder form nonpositive.

Comment: Thanks. How did you obtain $\log(1+x)\leq x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13x^3$ ?

Comment: I added some more description in the final remark, viz. Taylor expand and use Lagrange reminder form.

Comment: I think for $x>1$ inequality is trivial . So the extracting the bound $[-1,1]$ from  $x\in(-1,\frac32]$ is $[1,\frac {3}{2}]$, which is trivial. True ?

Comment: The series for $\ln(1+x)$ is enveloping so it is alternately above and below the limit.

Comment: Oh, that was just commenting on the last $\leq x$ part.  Of course $\log(1-x)$ wouldn't work with $x\geq 1$.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, we can assume here that $e^{x}\geq x+1$ is too weak , am I true ?

Comment: Yes, $e^x\geq x+1$ is too weak to prove our inequality for $x\in[-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

> $e^x \ge (x + 1)^{x + 2}(1 - x) \implies x \ge (x + 2)\ln(x + 1) + \ln(1 - x)$

Consider the function $f(x) = (x + 2)\ln(x + 1) + \ln(1 - x) - x$. If we can prove $\forall x \in (-1, 1)$ that $f(x) \le 0$ is strictly concave down with at most $1$ root, then it suffices to show $x \ge (x + 2)\ln(x + 1) + \ln(1 - x)$

Note that $f'(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x^2 - 1} + \ln{(x + 1)}$ and $f''(x) = \dfrac{x^3-3x^2 - x - 1}{(x^2 - 1)^2}$.

Let $g(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - x - 1$

$g'(x) = 0 \to 3x^2 - 6x-1 = 0$. $\therefore x = 1 \pm \dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$. Observe $g$ is a positive cubic with both $g(1 \pm \dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}) < 0$, which implies $g < 0$ over $x \in [-1, 1]$. Hence, $f''(x) < 0$ and $f$ is strictly concave down for $x \in (-1, 1)$.

Now consider, $x \ge \ln{(x + 1)} \ge \dfrac{x}{x+1}$. So we have, $\dfrac{2x}{x^2 - 1} + x \ge f'(x) \ge \dfrac{2x}{x^2 - 1} + \dfrac{x}{x + 1}$. See that both $x\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{x^2 - 1} + 1\right)$ and $x\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{x^2 - 1} + \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right)$ have only one and common root at $(0, 0)$. $\therefore 0 \ge f'(0) \ge 0$ or $f'(0) = 0$.

With, $f''(0) < 0$ and $f(0) = (0 + 2)\ln(0 + 1) + \ln(1 + 0) = 0$, we see that $f$ is strictly concave down and has a maximum at its only root. In other words, $f(x) \le 0$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Perhaps easier alternative is to use the OP's analysis re $~e^x \geq 1 + x,~$ which reduces the problem to examining the behavior of $~f(x) = (x+1)^{x+1}(1-x) - 1,~$ as per my comment following the original posting.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I noticed the comments and post. This is an approach that OP does not want, however, there are future users who may want a straight forward calculus approach with similar questions and hence it is posted. It would benefit in avoiding future duplicates from lack of answers due to OP's request in a particular method.